# Autocompletion when browsing ssh server in zsh

Tags: terminal, ssh, zsh, auto-complete

i realized that my zsh does not autocomplete the folders of a SSH server when I am in a local terminal and use `cd`, `rsync` or any other command. The bash in Ubuntu does this.

e.g.:

```
rsync -avh --progress user@host:/folder1/subfolder/another_subf . -n
```

the command works so I can connect, its just very uncomfortable when you have to type and know every foldername by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZSH can tab complete for `rsync` over SSH; the feature is probably simply not enabled in your ZSH. Here's what I see for a `localhost:` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
% rsync -avz . localhost:
Applications/  Desktop/       Documents/     Downloads/     Library/
...
```

First, you will ideally need automated login setup, unless you like typing your password after every TAB. For SSH this can be done with public key authentication, among other methods. There are other questions on how to set this up.

Then, in ZSH the completion system will need to be enabled. A minimal test of this is:

```
% zsh -f
lion% rsync -avz . localhost:
# (remote tab completion is not available, I hit control+c)
lion% autoload -U compinit
lion% compinit
lion% rsync -avz . localhost:
Applications/  Desktop/       Documents/     Downloads/     Library/
...
lion% exit
```

Therefore you will need to enable the completion system by placing the commands

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
```

into a ZSH "run command", usually `~/.zshrc` and then load a new shell with `exec zsh -l` or some similar action.

Comment: This works for my SSH server. However, maybe it's better to use `autoload -Uz`?

Comment: @gernophil uhhhh (... furiously reads `zshall` for the umpteenth time ...)

Comment: @thrig  -  `run-help` may  be your friend.  :-)

Comment: @fd0 not really, that just runs `man` which is an order of magnitude (or more) slower than my `numan` command.

Comment: @gernophil you would only need `-z` if you have set `KSH_AUTOLOAD` somewhere prior in your configuration; otherwise, there's not much point to delaying when the `compinit` code is run given that `compinit` is run right after the autoload line.